# 10 Posiciones aleatorias en una matriz sin repetirse en c sharp

Tags: c#, random, array-bidimensional

Como puedo generar 10 posiciones aleatorias de una matriz sin repetirse,tengo un codigo que lo hace pero es demasiado largo,quisiera ver si hay alguna manera de optimizarlo,tambien en esta funcion aveces se me repiten las posiciones ,pero ya hice do - while para que no se repitan

Tengo esta funcion:

```
static void randomposiciones( int[,]a){
        Random r = new Random();
    int fila1=0; int columna1=0;
    int fila2=0; int columna2=0;
    int fila3=0; int columna3=0;
    int fila4=0; int columna4=0;
     int fila5=0; int columna5=0;
    int fila6=0; int columna6=0;
     int fila7=0; int columna7=0;
    int fila8=0; int columna8=0;
     int fila9=0; int columna9=0;
     
    int fila = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0));
    int columna=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1));
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
    Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila+ " - " +columna);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila,columna]);
    do{
    fila1 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna1=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila==fila1 && columna==columna1);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Yellow;
     Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila1+" - " +columna1);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila1,columna1]);
     do{
    fila2 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna2=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila1==fila2 && columna1==columna2);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Blue;
     Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila2+" - " +columna2);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila2,columna2]);
     do{
    fila3 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna3=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila2==fila3 && columna2==columna3);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
     Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila3+" - " +columna3);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila3,columna3]);
    do{
    fila4 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna4=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila3==fila4 && columna3==columna4);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Cyan;
     Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila4+" - " +columna4);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila4,columna4]);
     do{
    fila5 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna5=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila4==fila5 && columna4==columna5);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Gray;
     Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila5+" - " +columna5);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila5,columna5]);
     do{
    fila6 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna6=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila5==fila6 && columna5==columna6);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Magenta;
     Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila6+" - " +columna6);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila6,columna6]);
    do{
    fila7 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna7=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila6==fila7 && columna6==columna7);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.White;
     Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila7+ " - "+columna7);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila7,columna7]);
     do{
    fila8 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna8=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila7==fila8 && columna7==columna8);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
    Console.Write("Elemento seleccionado de la posicion " +fila8+ " - " +columna8);
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila8,columna8]);
     do{
    fila9 = r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
    columna9=r.Next(0,a.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
    
   
    }while(fila8==fila9 && columna8==columna9);
    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Red;
     Console.Write("Elemento ");
    Console.WriteLine(": "+a[fila9,columna9]);
    }
```

Comment: Cual es el rango de los numeros aleatorios?

Comment: Los rangos son los tamanos de la matriz(FILA 0 ,FILA 10 Y COLUMNA 0 ,COLUMNA10 "ESTOS SERIAN LOS RANGOS SI LA MATRIZ FUERA DE 10 *10) ,ya que debo sacar aleatoriamenete posiciones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En lugar de introducir números y mirar si están repetidos, genera una lista de números sin repeticiones y extrae valores aleatoriamente de ahí:

```
int[,] matriz = new int[10,10];
Random r = new Random();

var numeros = Enumerable.Range(0, 99).ToList();

for (int indice = 0; numeros.Count() != 0; ++indice)
{
    var numero = numeros.ElementAt(r.Next(0, numeros.Count() - 1));
    matriz[indice / matriz.GetLength(0), indice % matriz.GetLength(1)] = numero;
    numeros.Remove(numero);
}

for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; ++y)
        Console.Write($"{matriz[y,x]:00} ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJPS8NAEMXPm08xFoUNTWNyrNGDlOKlilTBQ8lhTce40Ozi7rYmln72OPnT0CrksLPzm3nvLcnsJNMG63prpcrhpbIOi8Q7rcKFVF@J52UbYS08G50bUXh7j1knnMxgp@UaHoVU3DpDY6sUhMmt7zFimFRuFaRQCOr9wB0o/IbmLo6COEoTIpZCrXUBpm92JfdJkbGdMKC2BRptqT1vj@J9gyFROfIogOnUD1/1QlrXj3xoA5wUSGUtM6SxKDnuCGd6qwiEi/Z2PO4Ystp6PZFrzPQz8w0WqNy94yZ8wtI1qn/3TSD2/SYM64KuevHrPnj4gG6BKnefPPKDo7Wr/93YTwfpdt9RaYmF3iHvylbqcJa27IKWcAtxG60cUg1M1THVwFQNw9hMK6vpUd@MdMgvR/s@RBWU6U0UHWDUZTvj6K9A3huh71DXvw)</kbd>.

Comment: Similar al algoritmo Fisher–Yates.
¡Excelente!